# tar -z files to several server at once?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

What's a more efficient way to compress and tar the same files to several servers at once? Right now I have:

```
for SERVER in $SERVERS; do
  tar czpf - my/directory | ssh $SERVER tar xzpf - &
done && wait
```

It gets the job done, and running the loop in parallel is an improvement, but with ~20 servers that's a lot of redundant zipping on my end. Is there a way to compute the tarball only once, then duplicate that same output into each ssh command in the loop?

Comment: Why not use a temporary file to store the tarball?

Comment: compressing the folder again and again for each server is obviously the worst solution

Comment: @hek2mgl Right. But running the loop in parallel is at least better than not.

Comment: 1. Create the archive. 2. Transfer the file per ssh in parallel as you are doing.. I don't see a better solution.

Comment: Creating the archive separately would ultimately be better that the above, but it does serialize the local zip and remote unzip steps.

Comment: what is the problem with that? also how would you make sure that `directory` does not change during multiple runs of compression?

Comment: The problem is that it would go faster if all remotes could unzip at the same time the local machine was zipping. `directory` won't change because it won't.

Comment: Note how a pipe works: if data is read it is immediately removed from the pipe. That's why you cannot forward a pipe to multiple readers without duplicating it. If you use a temporary file multiple readers would be able to access it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72373/discussion-between-hek2mgl-and-chris).

Answer (score 3):

This will not be DRY, but process substitutions and `tee` can do it:

```
tar czpf - my/directory | tee \
    >(ssh server1 tar xzpf -) \
    >(ssh server2 tar xzpf -) \
    >(ssh server3 tar xzpf -) \
    >(ssh server4 tar xzpf -) \
    ...                       \
    >(ssh server20 tar xzpf -) \
    >/dev/null
```

Redirecting to `/dev/null` at the end prevents from printing the archive contents on the terminal.

...

I see this is just glglgl's point #1 spelled out explicitly. Made answer community wiki

Answer (score 2):

You could do something with `tee` and either a FIFO or (on more advanced shells, such as `bash`) use the [`>(command)`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) construct.

This could work in 2 possible ways:

1. You could build up your command line in a loop so that you end with a command like `tee >(ssh host1 tar xzpf -) >(ssh host2 tar xzpf -)`. How to do so in Bash is not completely clear to me; either you could use an array but I am not sure), or you'll have to use `eval`.
2. You could start with an "initial" named FIFO where the `tar` data is piped in. Then, on each iteration, you do `mkfifo next_pipe; tee <previous_pipe >(ssh ...) > next_pipe` create a named FIFO in each iteration. At the end, you'll have to `cat` the last pipe to `/dev/null` in order to start the while, complidated pipe.

   Something like

   ```
   mkfifo 0
   tar czpf - my/directory > 0
   i=0
   for SERVER in $SERVERS; do
       i=$((i+1))
       mkfifo $i
       tee <$((i-1)) >(ssh $SERVER tar xzpf) >$i &
   end
   ```

and then wait for all processes to finish. And then clean up your directory!

That said I personally would probably write a Python script which does all that `tee`ing stuff and which works via pipes, not via named FIFOs. That, among others, relieves from the pain to clean up at the end.

If that is not an option, using a local intermediate file seems the best solution to me.

But if it is, here is a first shot of a Python program which does the job. It is an ad-hoc shot which is completely untested, but shows the idea.

```
#/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import subprocess
cmd1 = sys.argv[1]
cmd2 = sys.argv[2]
hosts = sys.argv[3:]
sp1 = subprocess.Popen(cmd1, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
spn = []
for host in hosts:
    sp = subprocess.Popen(['ssh', host, cmd1], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    spn.append(sp)
while True:
    block = sp1.stdout.read(4096)
    if not block: break
    for sp in spn:
        sp.stdin.write(block)
c = sp1.wait()
for sp in spn:
    c2 = sp.wait()
    if not c: c = c2
sys.exit(c)
```

Can be called with

```
./program 'tar czpf - my/directory -' 'tar xzpf' host1 host2 host3 ...
```

Comment: How would you use tee to chain your output to multiple iterations of a loop?